# Django reusable application with linked FK?

Tags: python, django

I have the following scenario.

I have an existing application called ‘**Contacts**’ with it's model I have **number** and **name**.

I want to create a new application called ‘**unsubscribe**’ and I want to make it **reusable**.

**This is my issue:**

In the new app called unsubscribe it's model will need a foreign key relationg to the contact number. This now means that it is now tied to ‘contacts’ and I cannot use it for say my email app. **How does Django deal with this from a reusable point of view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [Generic Relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1) and create a [Generic Foreign Key](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey) relationship from the *unsubscribe* model to the *contacts* model. This allows you to abstract the relationship between your unsubscriptions and other objects, connecting them to any instance of a model in your project.

> A normal ForeignKey can only “point to” one other model, which means that if the TaggedItem model used a ForeignKey it would have to choose one and only one model to store tags for. The contenttypes application provides a special field type (GenericForeignKey) which works around this and allows the relationship to be with any model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic

class Unsubscription(models.Model):
    name = ...

    # These two fields allow you to manage the model & instance of object that 
    # this unsubscribe model instance is related to
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # This gives you an easy way to get access to the actual instance of the 
    # instance above
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')


# On the reverse end of the relationship you can add a Generic relation to 
# easily get access to all unsubscriptions related to this contact via the GFK
from myapp.models import Unsubscription
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = ...

    unsubscribtions = generic.GenericRelation(Unsubscribtion)
```

Answer (score 1):

Often it's ok to import models between apps.  This just creates a dependency, something many apps have.  Of course it's more flexible to have your app be independently pluggable, but  the important thing is that you document any dependencies for anyone else trying to use your app(s).

If you really want your app to be pluggable, consider reorganizing your app.  Simplicity is good, but going over-overboard and insisting on strict, literal adherence to principles can get in the way of functionality.

(Without specific details of your app, this is just speculation, but since all the apps you describe  revolve around Contacts, it seems like they could simply be repackaged into the same app with unsubscribe as boolean field in contacts and a view to set the attribute.  And depending on what exactly you want to do with Email, something similar)